# Show complete data in a TextBlock

Tags: c#, .net, layout, windows-phone-8, textblock

I am building an app for WindowsPhone where i need to show data in my TextBlock. As the size of the data is big i am using ScrollBar to display the data. I don't want to scroll horizontally. If the size of the data is huge i want to display it like a paragraph with vertical ScrollBar. Please see my Xaml :

```
<Canvas Height="659" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-40,91,0,0" Name="canvas2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="536">
            <Image Canvas.Left="76" Canvas.Top="26" Height="227" Name="newsimage" Stretch="Fill" Width="373" />
            <TextBlock Canvas.Left="76" Canvas.Top="274" Height="41" Name="datee" Text="" Width="200" Foreground="Green" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="24" />
           <ScrollViewer Margin="2,0,10,20"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AllowDrop="False" ManipulationMode="Control" Height="131" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Canvas.Left="76" Canvas.Top="347">
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="59" Canvas.Top="334" Height="124" Name="title" Text="" Width="410" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" />
           </ScrollViewer>
```

I want the last TextBlock i.e "title" to have vertical scrolling facility. Here i am not able to show the complete data;

Comment: done it.... need to give textwrap

Answer (score 1):

Set the `TextWrapping` Property to Wrap + `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to visible instead of auto to force the vertical scrolling :

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="0,0,0,476" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
                            This is just a stupid long text
                            Adding supported languages in the Project Properties tab will
                            new resx file per language that can carry the translated                      
                            values of your UI strings. The binding in these examples will  
                            cause the value of the attributes to be drawn from the .resx 
                            file that matches CurrentUICulture of the app at run time.
                </TextBlock>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

This works just fine